# Free SMTP for Production

Tags: node.js, express, smtp, nodemailer

Can we use free SMTP for production purposes?. Currently, I'm using Mailtrap to test my email sending functionality. But can I use it for production?? if not can I have a solution for a Free SMTP?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking a production system within a company, no.

Mailtrap says the free plan is for evaluation purposes only. There are some heavy rate limits, and only one mailbox, so if you're running this as part of a CI/CD pipeline often your tests would fail. (unless you're a *non-profit*, then they'll give you the 'team' plan for free)

You could look at postfix, but I don't know of any hosted solutions that would provide you their bandwidth for free in an unlimited capacity.